# Parsing Ints out of XML attributes

Tags: java

so i have an attribute to a node which contains something like this:
number="1"

i thought if i parse on `=` I could just use `Integer.parseInt(node.getAttributes().item(i).toString()));`

but this returns the following error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""1""
```

so now i'm doing:

```
String[] value = node.getAttributes().item(i).toString().split("=\"");
String[] number = value[1].split("\"");
Integer.parseInt(number[0].toString()) // contains the right value 1
```

is there a better, cleaner way of doing this? feel like this is cheesy..

**EDIT:**

node is defined this way:
 org.w3c.dom.Node node = nodeList.item(index);

Comment: What type/class is `node`?

Comment: oh sorry!  org.w3c.dom.Node node = nodeList.item(index)

Comment: which api did you use?  xml? you cannot get the value of an attribute?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace

```
node.getAttributes().item(i).toString()
```

with

```
node.getAttributes().item(i).getNodeValue()
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getNodeValue%28%29

Comment: The order for problem solving: 
Vendor Documentation => Dr. Google => StackOverflow